# React Redux App Deployed with Netlify URLs issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, netlify

My problem is simple. I built a React Redux app and tried to deploy it on Netlify. Everything worked perfectly, app online, SSL Cert installed, root page displayed, domain name... but whenever I try to access one of my routes like myapp.com/login I get a 404 error.

Your help would be precious and allow me to finally go live.

Many thanks, I hope I was clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since routing in a React application is handled by javascript, it is likely, that you did not set up a redirect rule. When you are requesting a certain route, the server doesnt find the route, because it doesn't know about your react routing. You basically have to redict all the requests to your index.html and let react handle all the routing. There is a guide on how to set that up for netlify [here](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#history-pushstate-and-single-page-apps)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your issue is with Netlify since as explained by Martin, react does the routing itself. Most likely what's happening is that your parent component doesn't have access to the react-router props, thus, whenever the url changes it doesn't go through shouldComponentUpdate. Assuming you have the right syntax,I would try wrapping your parent component with withRouter as follows:

```
import {withRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

class youComponent extends Component{
     constructor(props){
         super(props);
     }

     render(){
        let {teamName} = this.props;
        return(  
           <Switch>
               <Route path="/path2" component={ChildComponent} />
                ... other routes
               <Route path="/path3" render={(props) => <ChildComponent2 

teamName={teamName} />} />
              </Switch>
            )
      }
}

export default withRouter(yourComponent)
```

Also make sure your children components have access to the history props from react-router-dom. Sometimes the history props doesn't get passed down to the children components.